# How can i ignore: PSQLException: The column name clothStyle was not found in this ResultSet

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I created a a query to only get 4 items from a row in a table which does not include the column cloth style, so i understand why i get the error, but how can i tell Spring Jpa or JPA it is on purpose. and i just want the id, name and color table ?

this is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/query/material",method = RequestMethod.GET)

public String QueryMaterialTable(HttpServletRequest request){

    DataTableRequest<Material> dataTableInRQ = new DataTableRequest<Material>(request);
    PaginationCriteria pagination = dataTableInRQ.getPaginationRequest();

    String baseQuery = "SELECT id as id, time as time, name as name, color as color, price as price, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM MATERIAL) AS totalrecords  FROM MATERIAL";
    String paginatedQuery = AppUtil.buildPaginatedQuery(baseQuery, pagination);

    System.out.println(paginatedQuery);

    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(paginatedQuery, Material.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Material> materialList = query.getResultList();

    DataTableResults<Material> dataTableResult = new DataTableResults<Material>();
    dataTableResult.setDraw(dataTableInRQ.getDraw());
    dataTableResult.setListOfDataObjects(materialList);
    if (!AppUtil.isObjectEmpty(materialList)) {
        dataTableResult.setRecordsTotal(String.valueOf(materialList.size())
        );
        if (dataTableInRQ.getPaginationRequest().isFilterByEmpty()) {
            dataTableResult.setRecordsFiltered(String.valueOf(materialList.size()));
        } else {
            dataTableResult.setRecordsFiltered(String.valueOf(materialList.size()));
        }
    }
    return new Gson().toJson(dataTableResult);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got the question right, your problem is with the following two lines:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(paginatedQuery, Material.class);
List<Material> materialList = query.getResultList();
```

You have various options to fix this:

- provide a complete column list, i.e. provide the missing column in the SQL statement and just make them `NULL`;
- Don't use `Material` but a new class that has the matching attributes.
- [Don't use a native query but JPQL and a constructor expression](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor).
- [Use a `ResultTransformer`](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-use-the-hibernate-resulttransformer-to-customize-result-set-mappings/).
- [Use Spring Data and a Projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections).
- [Use a Spring `JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate).

Comment: Thanks, i was using this "provide a complete column list, i.e. provide the missing column in the SQL statement and just make them NULL;" but i wanted a better way. I would go with the result transformer, as i am using Jquery datatable and want a more flexible way of creating complicated ,dynamic query and still maintain a clean code base